# MYSQL /MariaDB - TokuDB ... no space left on device

Tags: mysql, mariadb, tokudb

Although there is some space left on the hard drive any insert on a table with the tokuDB storage engine fails  with the error:

Error Code: 1021. Disk full (); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 189 "Disk full")

Inserts on other storage engines (e.g. innodb ) are still working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a toku system parameter called: **tokudb_fs_reserve_percent**

Copied from https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/storage-engines/tokudb/tokudb-system-variables/#tokudb_fs_reserve_percent

**Description**: If this percentage of the filesystem is not free, inserts will be prohibited. Recommended value is half the size of the available memory. Once disabled, inserts will be re-enabled once twice the reserve is available. TokuDB will freeze entirely if the disk becomes entirely full.
**Scope**: Global
**Dynamic**: No
**Data Type**: numeric
**Default Value**: 5

So the default value is 5%. Either you change the paramter in your /etc/mysql/conf.d/tokudb.cnf to a lower value, e.g.

```
tokudb_fs_reserve_percent=0
```

or you free some disk space.